# The idea behind Green's theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, intuition, greens-theorem

What is the intuition behind green's theorem? Does it relate an area with only its boundary? What does a line integral in green's theorem represent?

Also, why is it useful?

I prefer the most simple answers because I just started learning about this topic.

Comment: [This webpage](http://mathinsight.org/greens_theorem_idea) attempts to give an intuitive/graphical interpretation of it.

Comment: Thanks, iv read many PDF concerning this topic but can the theorem ONLY be explained using physics?

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by explained using physics.  Do you mean experimentally or something?  The mechanical tool called a [planimeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planimeter) uses Green's theorem to allow measurement of area by drawing the boundary of a shape.  Maybe you could find one of them to mess around with?

Comment: From what I understood there are different line integrals and the one in greens theorem represents work , what am failing at understanding is what is this theorem good for ? why was it "invented " ?

Comment: There's only one line integral generically - $\int_\gamma f$ is the line integral of $f$ about some curve $\gamma$, and is defined in terms of the standard Riemann integral when, given some parametrization $g:[a,b]\to\gamma$, we have that $\int_\gamma f= \int_a^b f(g(t))g'(t)\mathrm{d}t$

Comment: As for why it was invented, ignoring certain things like "why is anything in math invented/discovered?", Green's theorem allows us a method to attack certain problems from a new direction.  Often if some double integral is too difficult, we can try to look at it in terms of a line integral instead (or vice versa).  Sometimes the line integral is trivial while the double integral isn't.  Additionally, Green's theorem allows for a very easy proof of Cauchy's theorem in complex analysis.

Comment: Green's theorem is one of the higher dimensional generalizations of the single variable fundamental theorem of calculus (Newton-Leibnitz) $$\int_a^bf(x)\,dx=F(b)-F(a)$$ with $F'(x)=f(x)$. Observe that this formula relates the definite integral of $f(x)$ over an oriented 1-dimensional blob (= a line segment traversed from left to right) to an integral over a 0-dimensional boundary of a different function. The 0-dimensional boundary consists of the end points of the line, and we assign signs to the end points to match with the orientation. Green's theorem does the same to a 2-dimensional

Comment: (cont'd) blob with a 1-dimensional boundary. The relation between $F$ and $f$ looks more complicated but actually is easy to remember after you learn about differential forms and exterior derivative. Later on you will see a lot of similar results: Stokes' theorem does the same to a 2-dimensional blob (curving inside a 3D space) and its 1-dimensional boundary. Gauss' theorem relates an integral over a 3D-blob to an integral over its 2D boundary. There will be higher dimensional generalizations - all with proofs coming down to FTC.

Comment: I've read somewhere that Green's theorem is some kind of extension of surveyor's formula, which is a formula for computing the area of a polygon.

Comment: Also, the fundamental theorem of calculus and Green's theorem may both be viewed as some sort of conservative law in a physics sense.